# Getting errors when install Luci on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, lua, openwrt, luci

I want to install Luci web interface on Ubuntu 16.04 . I tried to install Luci alone with git clone . But after running make file by

```
sudo make runuhttpd
```

I am getting some errors :

```
rm -f host/luci
ln -s ./usr/lib/lua/luci host/luci
rm -rf /tmp/luci-* || true
build/hostenv.sh /home/NEWUSER/Desktop/openwrt/build/uci/build/luci/host /usr/lib/lua /usr/lib/lua "/home/NEWUSER/Desktop/openwrt/build/uci/build/luci/host/bin/uci-defaults --exclude luci-freifunk-*"
/home/NEWUSER/Desktop/openwrt/build/uci/build/luci/host/bin/../etc/uci-defaults/luci-upnp: line 3: /etc/init.d/miniupnpd: No such file or directory
/home/NEWUSER/Desktop/openwrt/build/uci/build/luci/host/bin/../etc/uci-defaults/luci-minidlna: line 3: /etc/init.d/minidlna: No such file or directory
cp /home/NEWUSER/Desktop/openwrt/build/uci/build/luci/build/luci.cgi /home/NEWUSER/Desktop/openwrt/build/uci/build/luci/host/www/cgi-bin/luci
build/hostenv.sh /home/NEWUSER/Desktop/openwrt/build/uci/build/luci/host /usr/lib/lua /usr/lib/lua "/home/NEWUSER/Desktop/openwrt/build/uci/build/luci/host/usr/sbin/uhttpd -p 8080 -h /home/NEWUSER/Desktop/openwrt/build/uci/build/luci/host/www -f"
build/hostenv.sh: 8: build/hostenv.sh: /home/NEWUSER/Desktop/openwrt/build/uci/build/luci/host/usr/sbin/uhttpd: not found
Makefile:64: recipe for target 'runuhttpd' failed
make: *** [runuhttpd] Error 127
```

Any suggestion on this error ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same problem with this

home/engineer/repo/chetan_luci/luci/host/bin/../etc/uci-defaults/luci-minidlna: line 3: /etc/init.d/minidlna: No such file or directory

/home/engineer/repo/chetan_luci/luci/host/bin/../etc/uci-defaults/luci-upnp: line 3: /etc/init.d/miniupnpd: No such file or directory
c/luci/host/usr/sbin/uhttpd: not found
Makefile:64: recipe for target 'runuhttpd' failed
make: *** [runuhttpd] Error 127

Comment: Can Any explains step luci environment in  ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I got complete Vmware setup from http://jim-st.blogspot.in/2015_02_01_archive.html . I think this will give you complete Vmware .

Answer (score 0):

Openwrt's packages has some dependency marked within the makefiles, to run any package in x86 platform you have to compile it with all the dependencies.
In this case, from the shared logs it's clear that Luci is trying to launch uhttd(default web server for Luci) is not present hence the error.